# Django + HTMX - hx-get when pressing enter on an input text element only works once

Tags: django, htmx

happy new year.

I have a small problem that I don't understand why it happens.
I have the following code in a django template:

```html
<div class="input-group">
                    <input 
                        id="code-input" 
                        name="code-input" 
                        hx-get="{% url 'get-partial-data' %}" 
                        hx-trigger="keyup[key=='Enter']"
                        hx-swap="outerHTML" 
                        hx-target="#partial_data" 
                        class="form-control" 
                        type="text" 
                        placeholder="Search by code">
</div>
```

The idea is that when enter is pressed on the input, the GET request is triggered. That does happen, but only the first time. If for some reason I modify the value of the input and press enter again the request does not go out, the event is not fired.

Does anyone have any idea why this could happen?

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered the solution in a suggested question, change `hx-swap="innerHTML"` to `hx-swap="innerHTML"` .

Here is the original answer, [Why htmx trigger only work once in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71078150/why-htmx-trigger-only-work-once-in-django?rq=2)